# Output multiple errors as array from php as JSON encode in Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html, arrays, json

I'm having trouble by outputting multiple errors as arrays from my PHP file in JSON format to Jquery.

Normally data from PHP can be encoded as JSON and then sent to Jquery for outputting the code as Ajax success or error response. Works fine so far at least for `success:function(data)` since the data is fetched but not on `error:function()`. I put that same (data) in that function too but nothing returns.

How come? What I get is a response though at the end saying `undefined`. I don't even know if that's the right way to accomplish. Btw, within the PHP code there could be lots of error outputs all stored or stacked as array. It actually no matter.

HTML:

```
<div class="container" style="width:700px;">
    <div id="message"></div>
    <label>Select Image</label>
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
    <br />
    <img src="upload/no-image.png" id="uploaded_image" style="height: 256px; width: auto;" class="img-thumbnail">
</div>
```

JQUERY:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('change', '#file', function () {
        formdata.append("file", document.getElementById('file').files[0]);
        $.ajax({
            url: "upload.php",
            method: "POST",
            data: formdata,
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData: false,
            beforeSend: function () {
                $('#uploaded_image').html("<label class='text-success'>Image Uploading...</label>");
            },
            success: function (data) {
                $('#message').addClass('alert alert-success').html(data.reply);
                alert(data.reply);
                $('#uploaded_image').attr('src', data.imgURL);
            },
            error: function (data) {
                // $('#message').html(data.err);
                alert(data.err);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$err = array();

if ($_FILES["file"]["name"] != '') {
    // $test = explode('.', $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
    // $ext = end($test);

    $uploadDir = "upload/";
    $name = pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name'], PATHINFO_FILENAME);
    $extension = strtolower(pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
    $targetpath = $uploadDir . $name . '.' . $extension;

    if (file_exists($targetpath)) {
        $err[] = 'Sorry, file exists and cannot be processed';
        die;
    }

    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $targetpath)) {

        $response = array('imgURL' => $targetpath, 'reply' => 'Image uploaded successfully');
        echo json_encode($response);

        // echo '<img src="'.$targetpath.'" height="150" width="225" class="img-thumbnail" />';
    } else {

        $err[] = 'Nope, something went wrong';
        echo json_encode($err);

        // $error = array('err' => 'Nope, something went wrong');
        // echo json_encode($error);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: `header('Content-Type: application/json');` add this line before echoing `echo json_encode($err)`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$err = array();

if ($_FILES["file"]["name"] != '') {
    // $test = explode('.', $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
    // $ext = end($test);

    $uploadDir = "upload/";
    $name = pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name'], PATHINFO_FILENAME);
    $extension = strtolower(pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
    $targetpath = $uploadDir . $name . '.' . $extension;

    if (file_exists($targetpath)) {
        $err[] = 'Sorry, file exists and cannot be processed';
        die;
    }

    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $targetpath)) {

        $response = array('imgURL' => $targetpath, 'reply' => 'Image uploaded successfully');
        echo json_encode(array("status"=>true,"response"=>$response));

        // echo '<img src="'.$targetpath.'" height="150" width="225" class="img-thumbnail" />';
    } else {

        $err[] = 'Nope, something went wrong';
        echo json_encode(array("status"=>false,"error"=>$err));

        // $error = array('err' => 'Nope, something went wrong');
        // echo json_encode($error);
    }
}
?>
```

### JS

```
success: function (data) {
              if(data.status){
                $('#message').addClass('alert alert-success').html(data.response.reply);
                alert(data.response.reply);
                $('#uploaded_image').attr('src', data.response.imgURL);
              }else{
              $.each(data.error, function(k, v){
                 alert(v);
              });
              }
            },
```

You can send a status true false from your PHP and check in JS if the response is error or not. If its an error just loop through it and show your errors in HTML using `.append()` in JS.

Comment: by using your modified or altered code, it says 'undefined' at success / alert(data.reply) and nothing for data.error, kinda weird

Comment: Check my updated answer. Your reply key is within response array so you need to use data.response.reply, sorry forgot to mention that before and same for the imgURL. @what_me

Comment: Yep, now it works for when data.status is true but still no response from error. Nothing! Wonding why no error is thrown.

Comment: Can you please show the response you are getting when you get an error? Check your network tab and show me the response please. @what_me

Comment: Alright, now I got it but this is actually not nicely done. I also have to add that json_encode(array("status"=>false,"error"=>$err)); to every line with an error output e.g.     if (file_exists($targetpath)) {
        $err[] = 'Sorry, file exists and cannot be processed';
        die;
    }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167539/discussion-between-what-me-and-smit-raval).

Answer (score 0):

AJAX success function is called when the server responds correctly and doesn't throw an error, else, the error function is called. Therefore, when you are sending a JSON encoded value back successfully, the process is correct and therefore the success function will be called and not the error function.

Therefore, when you send $err back, the success function will be called as the process was completed successfully. Logically you are sending an error back, but for jquery, what matters is if the AJAX was completed successfully. Just check your JSON object to see if you have the error obj.

Modify your PHP

```
$err = array(errMsg => "Nope, something went wrong");
```

Modify your JS success function

```
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.errMsg != "")
            {
                 //Handle error
            }
            else
            {  
                $('#message').addClass('alert alert-success').html(data.reply);              
                alert(data.reply);
                $('#uploaded_image').attr('src', data.imgURL);
            }
        },
```

Comment: keeps nagging me with that undefined @ success and no return @ error